# Как типизировать массив с вложенными элементами?

Tags: javascript, typescript, интерфейс, типы

Есть массив (содержимое примерное):

```
let test: IRepo[] = [
    {'id': 1, 'test': 1, 'name': 'Иван'},
    {'id': 2, 'test': 2, 'name': 'Олег'},
    {'id': 3, 'test': 3, 'name': 'Виталий'},
    {'id': 4, 'test': 4, 'name': 'Аркадий' // ключей может быть много},
    // объектов может быть много
]

interface IRepo {
    // ???
}
```

Как описать интерфейс, если нужен только ключ 'name', остальные ключи не нужны?

Answer (score 2):

```
interface IRepoEntry {
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface IRepo {
  [index: number]: IRepoEntry;
}

const test: IRepo = [
    {'id': 1, 'test': 1, 'name': 'Иван'},
    {'id': 2, 'test': 2, 'name': 'Олег'},
    {'id': 3, 'test': 3, 'name': 'Виталий'},
    {'id': 4, 'test': 4, 'name': 'Аркадий'},
    {'id': 4, 'test': 4, 'name': 'Аркадий', 'data': new Object}, // ключей может быть много},
    // объектов может быть много
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде вот так валидный вариант.
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBGIM5gXBAkgJRABwPYG0C6EBeCbAKAnIgG8ByASwBNrEBGAGgmujiYjY4DsAhgFsQPaoAwQQEwggBhBAvCDUAvqzIUaDHgCZ2nWGC06ho8YDwQQNwggVhBAzCBKVFKnUaIAzDq76XhkWMTVASCCAHCCAQiAyZgGAnCC2quTqThAALG56PIkC3uKACCCAAiCAXCAygCwgEVH2sSlJ3Iip1EY+HNl5hZE69IJggjz8IADuEADyAEYAViAAxmDKEAD0kxA5ZoByIIDiIBbhEIA8IIB8IIBsIBZBEICMIIDSIEGAMiDrchtWG8rRUzMb+4BSIBY5QRtS69u7B8dnaxdXEi4EgkWj8aAAJwAZoIRiBkGgsFRVAxEPwAK7CfogCEAblU7jRmOxeNUNUQcAhYIA5vjyNgANYgACeFLAVP41NwiEE-GZJEUQA)

```js
let test: IRepo[] = [
    {'id': 1, 'test': 1, 'name': 'Иван'},
    {'id': 2, 'test': 2, 'name': 'Олег'},
    {'id': 3, 'test': 3, 'name': 'Виталий'},
    {'id': 4, 'test': 4, 'name': 'Аркадий'},
    {'id': 4, 'test': 4, 'name': 'Аркадий', 'data': new Object}, // ключей может быть много},
    // объектов может быть много
]

interface IRepo {
  id: number;
  test: number;
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any
}
```